# C# - Sort method for class interface object ,error

Tags: c#

I am trying to sort list with clubs  which have best result, I must use Sort Method, but it shows error, what I am doing wrong. I know it is a problem of Sort method but can't find a mistake, I made it work with lambda expression but I want to do it with sort method;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program

{
    public static void Main()

    {
        // class with objects
        Club barca = new Club("Barcelona", 1900, 100, 20);
        Club Real = new Club("Real", 1910, 80, 70);
        Club Manchester = new Club("Manchester", 1890, 75, 55);
        Club Milan = new Club("Milan", 1880, 45, 65);

        //new list of clubs
        var myclublist = new List<IClub>();

        ///add clubs in list
        myclublist.Add(barca);
        myclublist.Add(Real);
        myclublist.Add(Manchester);
        myclublist.Add(Milan);

        // sort method for list
        myclublist.Sort();

        //show clubs name with best results
        foreach (var item in myclublist)

        {
            if (item.IsPositiveBallRatio() == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ClubName());
            }
        }
    }


    // club class

    public class Club : IClub, IComparable<Club>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Scoredgoals { get; set; }
        public int Lossgoals { get; set; }

        public Club(string name, int year, int scoredgoals, int lossgoals)

        {
            Name = name;
            Year = year;
            Scoredgoals = scoredgoals;
            Lossgoals = lossgoals;
        }


        public int BallRatio()

        {
            int ratio;
            ratio = Scoredgoals - Lossgoals;
            return ratio;
        }



        public bool IsPositiveBallRatio()
        {
            if (Scoredgoals > Lossgoals)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }


        public string ClubName()

        {
            string n;
            n = Name;
            return n;
        }

        public int CompareTo(Club other)
        {
            return BallRatio().CompareTo(other.BallRatio());
        }
    }

    // inferface for club class
    interface IClub

    {
        int BallRatio();
        bool IsPositiveBallRatio();
        string ClubName();
    }
}
```

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well., `but it shows error` what was that?

Comment: @SubashKharel that is very strange suggestion for `void` method that mutates list...

Comment: AC Milan was founded in 1899 >:( :P Also, I guess you wanted to have properites in your interface, not methods.

Comment: un-time exception (line 26): Failed to compare two elements in the array.
Stack Trace:
[System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.]
   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.InsertionSort(T[] keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntrospectiveSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)

Answer (score 1):

Why: `IClub` is not comparable to itself and there is no other information about the type available to the code at run-time for generic method. So it falls back to non-generic version of `IComparable` which is not implemented by your `Club` type.

Fixes:

- either use list of `Club` instead of `List<IClub>` as `Club` is comparable to itself
- implement non-generic `IComparable` on the `Club`:

  ```
  public class Club : IClub, IComparable<Club> , IComparable
  {
    ...
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
      return CompareTo(obj as Club);
    }
  }
  ```
- make type you have in the list (`IClub`) to be comparable to itself - `IClub : IComparable<IClub>` to fix the issue if you really expect mixed `IClub` implementations in the array:

  ```
  public class Club : IClub, IComparable<Club> 
  {
    ...
    public int CompareTo(IClub other)
    {
      return CompareTo(other as Club);
    }
  }

  public interface IClub  : IComparable<IClub> {...}
  ```

See [List.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

Note: `CompareTo` in this post are sample-only and you need to add all type/null checks for them to work in real code.

Comment: _"I'd expect `IClub : IComparable<Club>` to fix the issue"_ -- did you try `IClub : IComparable<IClub>`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes, and indeed it works - see edit. (Now looking at my own remark in original version I'm not really sure why I expected it to work... fail :) )

Comment: @lekinio hard to believe... At very least using `List<Club>` should have worked... Hope you find solution for your problem...